# What does nscannedObjects = 0 actually mean?

Tags: mongodb

As far as I understood, nscannedObjects entry in the explain() method means the number of documents that MongoDB needed to go to find in the disk.

My question is: when this value is 0, what this actually mean besides the explanation above? Does MongoDB keep a cache with some documents stored there?

Comment: It means that an index was used. Indexes are data structures containing only parts of the documents which allow fast searching.

Comment: That's precisely what is confusing me. I imagine the MongoDB memory as if it was an array (or any other similar data structure) containing the indexes (as a pointer/reference to the object in the disk, where the document is actually stored). But this clashes with the nscannedObjects = 0, because it means that MongoDB didn't need to go to the disk. Where am I wrong?

Comment: index is an entire data structure, like a tree. It contains links from some attributes to _id - if your search criteria is based SOLELY on the index - you can look at the index only. and not at the documents themselves - since they don't provide more information for selecting documents. It doesn't mean that mongo doesnt FETCH the documents eventually - just that they were not fetched for the selection phase.

Comment: Domas - or to put it another way if you have physical, paper files of people, arranged alphabetically, and are told to fetch guys between C and E, you just pick the C, D, E files without looking at the actual papers inside the files - which might just be references to other files somewhere in the basement. The fetching of things from the basement is what this statistic you cited measures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongo is a document database, which means that it can interpret the structure of the stored documents (unlike for example key-value stores).

One particular advantage of that approach is that you can build indices on the documents in the database.

Index is a data structure (usually a variant of b-tree), which allows for fast searching of documents basing on some of their attributes (for example `id` (!= `_id)` or some other distinctive feature). These are usually stored in memory, allowing very fast access to them.

When you search for documents basing on indexed attributes (let's say `id` > 50), then mongo doesn't need to fetch the document from memory/disk/whatever - it can see which documents match the criteria basing solely on the index (note that fetching something from disk is several orders of magnitude slower than memory lookup, even with no cache). The only time it actually goes to the disk is when you need to fetch the document for further processing (and which is not covered by the statistic you cited).

Indices are crucial to achieve high performance, but also have drawbacks (for example rarely used index can slow down inserts and not be worth it - after each insertion the index has to be updated).

Comment: I see. So the nscannedObjects is the number of documents that MongoDB needed to fetch from disk in order to find the ones which matched the filters of the query, but not the ones that actually fetch from disk to be returned as the output, right?

Comment: Yup. There is another statistic probably called nFetchedDocuments which tells you precisely how many were fetched at the end.

Answer (score 1):

nscannedObjects=0 means that there was no fetching or filtering to satisfy your query, the query was resolved solely based on indexes. So for example if you were to query for `{_id:10}` and there were no matching documents you would get nscannedObjects=0.

It has nothing to do with the data being in memory, there is no such distinction with the query plan.

Note that in MongoDB 3.0 and later nscanned and nscannedObjects are now called  totalKeysExamined and totalDocsExamined, which is a little more self-explanatory.